# Is it possible to create a new asset from an image URL?

Tags: plugin-development, assets, image, assetfilemodel

I've created several entries from a feed from the eBay API, but I would like to add images to the entry too!

I've managed to get an array of URLs, which I would like to import into an assets field that I have on the new entries.

I saw a post from Brandon from a couple years back suggesting it was not possible to do this, unable to find anything more up-to-date.

Could I grab the image with cURL in my plugin then create a `new AssetFileModel` and some how sync the temp image file with Craft somehow? As a follow up question how would I add multiple images to the assets field on my new entry?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the image into a temp file, then upload it as an asset. You can find $iAssetSourceId by looking at the URL when editing an asset source

```
$iAssetSourceId = 4;
$iAssetFolderId = (int)craft()->assets->getRootFolderBySourceId($iAssetSourceId)->id;
$sTempFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $sFilename;
$sFileContents = file_get_contents($sImageUrl);
file_put_contents($sTempFilePath, $sFileContents);

// Get craft to copy the temp file into the assets folder
$oAssetOperationResponse = craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
    $sTempFilePath,
    $sFilename,
    $iAssetFolderId,
    AssetConflictResolution::Replace
);

return (int)$oAssetOperationResponse->responseData["fileId"];
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the `AssetsHelper::getTempFilePath($extension);` helper for the temporary file path.

Comment: Any idea what the equivalent of `craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath()` is for Craft 3?

Comment: It seems Craft 3 does use `insertFileByLocalPath`. I was able to handle this by simply creating a new `Asset` element and saving it. When doing so, you just need to set the `tempFilePath` property of the element to the path you put the file to in the beginning. i.e. `$asset = new Asset(); $asset->tempFilePath = $sTempFilePath; $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE); Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);` You'll also want to set a few other properties such as `filename`, `folderId`, & `volumeId`.